# vncserver not opening port

Tags: vnc

I have been trying to get my vncserver fixed, it seems that I broke something when I was trying to get it working with the ubuntu gnome desktop, basically, I'm pretty new to linux and I no longer know what I did but I had someone with more experience look into it and they couldn't figure it out either.
The issue is that the vncserver runs and the ports appear to be open on the linux machine to which I only have access via ssh, but when I try to access those ports from another machine or even scan the server (its local) for open ports  the only ones I get are the ssh and port 80 for nginx.
I've tried resetting the vncserver several times and I've also ensured that the firewall wasnt blocking them.

edit: this is what i get from uwf status:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
5901/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5901:5910/tcp              ALLOW       Anywhere
5902/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5902:5910/tcp              ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5901/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5901:5910/tcp (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5902/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5902:5910/tcp (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I'm not sure what other information to give but I've been trying to fix this for some time and it seems pointless, nothing fixes this issue, i think i will just go ahead and reinstall the whole thing

Comment: Can you give more information about it ? Also give output of ufw status ?

Comment: Please add the output of `ss -ltn`

Comment: What vnc server are you using?

Comment: I needed that working asap so I just reinstalled the whole thing, it's gone now, cheers anyways